# Type changing not behaving as expected

Tags: go, types, casting

I was solving a coding question that asked to check whether a given array contains all the rotations of a given string and I originally came up with this solution:

```
type myArr []string

func ContainAllRots(strng string, arr []string) bool { 
   if strng == "" {
      return true
    }

   arr = myArr(arr)

   for i := 0; i < len(strng); i++ {
      if !arr.Contains(strng[i:] + strng[:i]) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return true
}

func (a myArr) Contains(strng string) bool {
  for _,s := range a {  
    if s == strng {
      return true
    }
  }

  return false

}
```

Please ignore the fact that this might not be the best/most efficient solution to the given problem, but yeah so I was getting this error message:

`arr.Contains undefined (type []string has no field or method Contains)`

I thought with the line `arr = myArr(arr)` I would be changing the type of `arr` and therefore be able to call the `Contains` method on it, but I guess that logic didn't work. Can anyone tell me what is happening under the hood here and why I'm not assigning my new custom type back to `arr`?

Comment: You cannot change the type of a variable. `arr` is a `[]string`. Try using a different name, like `a:=myArr(arr)`, then `a` should have `Contains`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The "problem"

Go is, for the most part, is a language with static type system (or "with static typing").
Among other things, this means any variable in a program has *implicit* type with which the variable was *declared.*
To say that in other words, the type of a variable is not somehow stored *in* it, and hence cannot be changed by assigning to it a value of a nother type.

Hence if you have

```golang
type myArr []string

func foo(arr []string) {
    arr = myArr(arr)
}
```

The assignment is illegal since otherwise it would mean changing the type of the variable `arr` to `myArr`.

#### What you can do about it?

The approach to use in this case is to simply use another variable of a suitable type.

This might look like wasting of resources but

- Such wasting is negligible, and anyway don't optimize which is not proven to be slow.
- The reassigning you attempted may look neat but at the same time it might confuse the reader: as the same variable would have different method sets before and after the assignment.

For completeness, we should mention that Go has special means which allow the programmer to actually have variables which may change their type at runtime; these means are provided by *interfaces.*

For instance, both assignments in the code below are perfectly legal:

```golang
type I interface {
  Foo()
}

type A struct{}

func (a A) Foo() {}

type B struct{}

func (b B) Foo() {}

var v I

v = A{}
v = B{}
```

The variable `v` has the type `I` which is an interface type, and so it's expected to contain *interface values.*
Both the assignments change the so-called *dynamic type* of the variable `v`—to `A` and then to `B`, respectively, while its static type remains `I`.

I would note that in your particular case using interfaces is not called for but it's something to learn about.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` has been declared of type `[]string` due to the function signature of `ContainAllRots`. You can fix this by using a different name for `arr` on the left side of the assignment in `arr = myArr(arr)`.

For example:

```
type myArr []string

func ContainAllRots(strng string, arr []string) bool {
    if strng == "" {
        return true
    }

    mArr := myArr(arr)

    for i := 0; i < len(strng); i++ {
        if !mArr.Contains(strng[i:] + strng[:i]) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func (a myArr) Contains(strng string) bool {
    for _, s := range a {
        if s == strng {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false

}
```